# Angular json.data() as array[]

Tags: javascript, json, angular

i'm trying to extract data from a json file located and put it in an array. Currently i'm getting these errors:

```
zone.js:2933 GET http://localhost:4200/app/persons.json 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): undefined
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at zone.js:873
```

this is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actor } from '../model/actor';
// import { ACTORS } from './mock-actors';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ActorService {
    private actorsUrl = '/app/persons.json';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    getActors(): Promise<Actor[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.actorsUrl)
            .toPromise().then(response => response.json().data as Actor[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message);
    }
}
```

my model

```
export class Actor {
    lastName: string;
    profession: string;
    bio: string;
    url: string;
    imageUri: string;
    name: string;
    id: number;
    realName: string;
}
```

the json file looks something like this

```
{"personList":[{"lastName":"Wolowitz","profession":"Aerospace Engineer","bio":"Howard Joel Wolowitz, M.Eng is a fictional character on the CBS television series The Big Bang Theory, portrayed by actor Simon Helberg. Among the main male characters in the show, Howard is distinguished for lacking a doctoral degree, for still living with his mother, and for believing himself to be a \"ladies' man\". Simon Helberg's character is named after a computer programmer known by the show's co-creator Bill Prady.","url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Helberg","imageUri":"Howard_Wolowitz.jpg","name":"Howard","id":"howard","realName":"Simon Helberg"},{"lastName":"Hofstadter","profession":"Experimental physicist","bio":"Leonard Leakey Hofstadter, Ph.D., is a fictional character on the CBS television series The Big Bang Theory, portrayed by actor Johnny Galecki. Leonard is an experimental physicist originally from New Jersey who shares an apartment with colleague and friend Dr. Sheldon Cooper (Jim Parsons). Leonard and Sheldon are named after actor/producer Sheldon Leonard, and Nobel Prize Laureates Robert Hofstadter and Leon Cooper.\nLeonard has been described as the straight man of the series. Penny (Kaley Cuoco) is Leonard's next-door neighbor and main love interest, and the teasing of romance between the two of them is a major force driving the series. For his portrayal, Galecki was nominated for a Primetime Emmy Award and a Golden Globe Award.","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Galecki","imageUri":"Leonard_Hofstadter.jpg","name":"Leonard","id":"KLJSMLND","realName":"Johnny Galecki"}}
```

**EDIT**

in order to have connection to the api i have set up a proxy like this

```
{ 
"/app/*":{ 
"target": "appfoundry-restdemo.herokuapp.com/";, "secure": false, "logLevel": "debug" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: the path needs to be relative to your current ts file. Check your path

Comment: Try using relative path of the json file you're accessing.

Comment: I need to use a proxy in order to have a connection to the json file.
this is the proxy file:

{
  "/app/*":{
    "target": "http://appfoundry-restdemo.herokuapp.com/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

Inside the response method **response.json().data** insted of   **response.json().data as Actor[]**

```
getActors(): Promise<Actor[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.actorsUrl)
        .toPromise().then(response => <Actor[]>response.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: This indeed fixed the 404 problem! in network i can now see the objects. Still trying to figure out how to get them to show though however this wasn't part of the question i suppose so thanks!